# Change pause button of audio player on oncomplete listener in android

Tags: android, audio

I'm loading audio sounds into a listview, I play them.When the audio playing is done, i want to change that specific sound's pause button to play button again.
here is my code to play sounds

```
soundChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                try {

                    player.setDataSource(url);
                    // file.close();
                    player.prepare();
                    player.setLooping(false);
                    // player.start();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (player.isPlaying()) {
                    if (player != null) {
                        player.pause();
                        // Changing button image to play button
                        soundChild.setImageResource(R.drawable.playbutton);
                    }
                } else {
                    // Resume song
                    if (player != null) {
                        player.start();
                        // Changing button image to pause button
                        soundChild.setImageResource(R.drawable.pausebutton);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

          player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

          @Override public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) { // TODO
         // Auto-generated method stub player.release(); player=null;
              Toast.makeText(_context, "complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              soundChild.setImageResource(R.drawable.playbutton);

              player.reset();


          } });
```

But on complete listner the imageview of player button is never changed back to play imageview again. I doin't know where i'm doing wrong, because if onComplete is being called then imageview background should also change.please help.

Comment: Is onCompletion() run on UI thread? You can try wrapping `soundChild.setImageResource(R.drawable.playbutton);` in runOnUiThread.

Comment: i'm using this in getview of adapter. where should i put runOnUiThread?

Answer (score 0):

Usually You have to call requestLayout before:

```
      soundChild.requestLayout();
      soundChild.setImageResource(R.drawable.playbutton);
```

and then after changing the image

```
      soundChild.invalidate();
```

What else could You try? If it doesn´t work, You can also try:

```
      soundChild.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.playbutton));
```

Because, like described in the API for setImageResource:

> This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can
>   cause a latency hiccup

Also, what it is possible, You have to call it in on ui thread:

```
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

          @Override
           public void run() {
               soundChild.setImageResource(R.drawable.playbutton);
              }
         });
```

and call this in onCompletion.

Comment: is there any error? logcat output? but You are sure the onComplete is fired?

Comment: and is onComplete is surely called?

Comment: it is actually updating imageview of some other row

Comment: ok, and the toast is also fired? Maybe take a try on my edit with the runOnUiThread...

Comment: where should i put runOnYiThread? as I'v set OnComplete in getview of adapter.

Comment: aha, that´s a special thing :) . You have to reference the activity inside the adapter and than call in onCompletion activity.runOnUiThread() . Just reference it as a adapters parameter.